# Thread safety c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have a question about several segments in code, that set or get value of static element (using locks).

So, is this code correct? And what happens if I call MethodB and MethodC at one moment? actually, they both call one static method at one moment(from different lock() segments), is it safe?

```
public class ThreadsClass
{
    public static class StaticHelper
    {
        public static string NameStatic { get; set; }

        public static void MethodCountStatic(int num)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} step...",i);
            }
        }
    }

    private Object lockObject = new Object();

    public void MethodA()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            StaticHelper.NameStatic = "somename";
        }
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            StaticHelper.MethodCountStatic(1000000);
        }           
    }

    public void MethodC()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            StaticHelper.MethodCountStatic(500000000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct for what? It's fantasy cocde and it will work in some fantasy scenarios. And it will fail in others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes and no.

In the current state of the code, it's thread safe since `MethodCountStatic` does not keep any state, and nothing reads `NameStatic`. I assume that won't always be the case.

There are at least two problems if you go on building on the code;

- `StaticHelper` is public, so *any class* can call any method or access any property in it without locking.
- If you create two instances of `ThreadsClass`, they have two different locks so they'll not be prevented from calling or accessing properties in StaticClass without seeing each others' locks.

If you want the class thread safe, you'll need to make `StaticHelper` private and `lockObject` static to overcome the two problems.

EDIT: If you want to make StaticHelper public and keeping state, you're probably better off moving the locks inside the class itself instead, a'la;

```
public static class StaticHelper
{
    private static Object lockObject = new Object();
    private static string _nameStatic;

    public static string NameStatic { 
        get { lock (lockObject) return _nameStatic;  }
        set { lock (lockObject) _nameStatic = value; }
    }

    public static void MethodCountStatic(int num) {
        lock (lockObject) {
            // Your method here...
        }
    }
}
```

That way, the locking is isolated to the class that needs it instead of spread over a lot of unrelated classes.

Comment: Joachim Isaksson, thx for response !

But what if I want to make `StaticHelper` global static class and provide safety access to it methods and properties from all places(and different threads) of my application. Are there any opportunities to provide such functionality?

Comment: @user3648230 Added an edit about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! And would not it be a problem, that parameter [int num] of my static method can be different in different calls? For example what happens if 2 threads at one moment call MethodCountStatic(100) and MethodCountStatic(200) ?

Comment: @user3648230 Local variables (like `i` here) are local per function call and are (as long as you don't store it in a member variable or explicitly pass them over to another thread) thread safe by design. In other words, you don't really need to lock `MethodCountStatic` in your original code since it doesn't have any shared state with other calls of the same method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in current case functional for methods `MethodB` аnd `MethodC` is thread safe. But it is possible to access public members of static class ignoring this methods, be aware.